# JQuery: Capture the "just before removed" event when an element is being removed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My use case:

- I'm using the last jQuery version (which is at this time v-3.1.1).
- I'm adding the jQuery-UI because I need the `on('remove')` event.
- I suppose that I have a list of elements. One or more elements can be removed (from the DOM) by an external lib (*exampleLib.js*) I'm using.
- I can't edit the source code of *exampleLib.js* (it's hosted on the provider CDN and it's updated regularly by the provider).
- I need to capture the **just before event when an element is being removed**.
  Something like this (so it should output '01' then '02' when 'cElement' is removed):

  ```
  // of course this is not working
  // this the event I'm looking for
  $("#cElement").on("preremove", function () { console.log("01"); });

  $("#cElement").on("remove", function () { console.log("02"); });
  ```

Is that possible?

Below is an emulation of the scenario with an on-click event:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function preremoveEvent(){
    console.log("Before removing element event... ");
  }
    
  $("#btnRemove").on("click", function () {
    preremoveEvent();
    $("#cElement").remove();
  });

  $("#cElement").on("remove", function () {
    console.log("'C' Element was removed");
  });

});
```

```css
#cElement{color: #900; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<button id="btnRemove">Remove "User-C" element</button>
<ul>
 <li data-important="a" data-also-important="aa">User-A</li>
 <li data-important="bb" data-also-important="bb">User-B</li>
 <li id="cElement" data-important="c" data-also-important="cc">User-C</li>
 <li data-important="d" data-also-important="dd">User-D</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I guess it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to log something anytime the `remove` event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right it should work if you bind your own `on("remove")` event handler before the exampleLib.js is included and can bind the same event handler also on `on("remove")`.

Events are handled in the order they are bound in jQuery so if you bind first you are called first and have simulated the desired "preremoveEvent".

If this is not like you want please update your question and provide more details (like Twisty already asked).